# Rails are postgreSQL booleans different from mySQL booleans?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using that problem that nothing gets saved on my server that uses PostgreSQL.

I have this action here, that updates a boolean it works on my local machine that uses mySQL:

```
def reel_online

    @movie = Photographer.find(params[:id])

    if @movie.reel_online == false
      @movie.update_attributes(:reel_online => true)
    else
      @movie.update_attributes(:reel_online => false)
    end

    render :nothing => true
end
```

The strange thing is that with firebug I can see there is no error on the server, but the boolean dos not get changed.

**UPDATE:**
I changed my action to:

```
def reel_online

    @movie = Photographer.find(params[:id])

    if @movie.reel_online == 'f'
      @movie.update_attributes(:reel_online => 't')
    else
      @movie.update_attributes(:reel_online => 'f')
    end

    render :nothing => true
end
```

Still there is no error but the boolean is not saved. And my count of true reel_online is 0: `<%= @movies.where(:reel_online => 't').count %>` In my MySQL database I have set all reel_online to `0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109060/rails-3-migrations-boolean-mysql-vs-postgresql

Comment: I have updated my question still have problems.

Comment: By the way, a better way to write that would be `@movie.update_attributes(:reel_online => !@move.reel_online)`. Just a tip.

Comment: It's just more concise. Not a big deal really, just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: what does !@move.reel_online do?

Comment: Sets it to the opposite of the current value, which is what your if/else is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in my controller I should use `true` and `false` and in view it should be:

```
<%= @movies.where(:reel_online => 't').count %>
```